# Calculus on limits

Tags: limits

Can you answer this question: Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ a function defined by:
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
(x+y)^2\cos(1/x)\cos(1/y) & \text{if $xy\neq0$}\\
0 & \text{if $xy=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Show that $$\lim_{x\to 0}(\lim_{y\to 0}f(x,y))$$ not exist?
Thank you

Comment: What do you know about $\cos(a)$ as $a\to\infty$?

Comment: You should say what you have tried, where you are blocked... Otherwise your questions will be closed sooner or later. Morever try to write correct English: 'limite"  is "limit" in English, "existe" is "exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By letting $y=\frac{1}{2k\pi}$ and then $y=\frac{1}{2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2}}$then $k\rightarrow\infty$ iff $y\rightarrow0$ apply this to your $y$ as you get different result the limit does not exist.

Comment: You are welcome. Wish it help.